# parsing XML using cElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a problem with parsing an XML file using python, namely - syntax.

My XML files look like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE chunkList SYSTEM "ccl.dtd">
<chunkList>
 <chunk id="ch1" type="p">
  <sentence id="s1">
   <tok>
    <orth>dzisiaj</orth>
    <lex disamb="1"><base>dzisiaj</base><ctag>adv:pos</ctag></lex>
   </tok>
   <tok>
    <orth>uczę</orth>
    <lex disamb="1"><base>uczyć</base><ctag>fin:sg:pri:imperf</ctag></lex>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:syns_id">1449</prop>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:syns_rank">1449/0.3151019143 52662/0.2635524432 58124/0.2227816629 58122/0.1985639796</prop>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:unitsstr">szkolić.1(29:cumy) nauczać.1(29:cumy) kształcić.1(29:cumy) edukować.1(29:cumy) uczyć.1(29:cumy)</prop>
   </tok>
   <tok>
    <orth>się</orth>
    <lex disamb="1"><base>się</base><ctag>qub</ctag></lex>
   </tok>
   <tok>
    <orth>o</orth>
    <lex disamb="1"><base>o</base><ctag>prep:acc</ctag></lex>
   </tok>
   <tok>
    <orth>świecie</orth>
    <lex disamb="1"><base>świat</base><ctag>subst:sg:loc:m3</ctag></lex>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:syns_id">7826</prop>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:syns_rank">7826/0.1761356163 43462/0.1512730526 8139/0.1506959982 8361/0.1446884158 3331/0.1435643398 10819/0.1251661757 3332/0.1084764017</prop>
    <prop key="sense:ukb:unitsstr">cywilizacja.1(11:grp) krąg_kulturowy.1(11:grp) kultura.3(11:grp) krąg_cywilizacyjny.1(17:rsl) świat.2(11:grp)</prop>
   </tok>
  </sentence>
 </chunk>
</chunkList>
```

And what i need, is a list containing tuples with two values, `<orth>` and `<prop key="sense:ukb:syns_id">`. Every tuple is for every `<tok>` tag. so, for example for second `<tok>` i need a result like `(uczę, 1449)`.

I have written pseudocode about how i think it should work, but i have no idea how to implement it using ET.

Here it is:

```
ResultArray=[]

def treeSearch(root):
    for element in root:
        if element == 'tok':
            temp1=0
            temp2=0
            for tokens in element:
                if token == 'orth':
                    temp1=token.value()
                if token == 'prop key="sense:ukb:syns_id"':
                    temp2=token.value()
            tempTuple=(temp1,temp2)
            resultArray.append(tempTuple)

    return ResultArray
```

Comment: so you want to capture only the 1st tag `<prop>` within `<tok>` tag?

Comment: I want to capture `<orth>` and `<prop key="sense:ukb:syns_id">` in every `<tok>` and save it as a tuple.

Comment: `<orth>` is always there, but if there is no `<prop key=...>`, i can just use 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `xml.etree.ElementTree` module:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('input.xml').getroot()
result = []
for tok in root.findall('.//tok'):
    result.append((tok.findtext('orth'), tok.findtext('prop[@key="sense:ukb:syns_id"]') or 0))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[('dzisiaj', 0), ('uczę', '1449'), ('się', 0), ('o', 0), ('świecie', '7826')]
```

---

Details:

- `for tok in root.findall('.//tok'):` - iterating through all `<tok>` tags
- `tok.findtext('orth')` - will get text content of the `<orth>` tag withing current processed `<tok>` tag
- `tok.findtext('prop[@key="sense:ukb:syns_id"]') or 0` - get text content of the `<prop>` tag with specified `key` attribute. If it's not exists - leave the value as zero `0`

Comment: I HAVE BEEN TRYING FOR HOURS TO MAKE THIS WORK, AND THIS DOES. God bless you sir. Would you like to explain it tho?

Comment: @AwangardowyKaloryfer, you're welcome. See my details